# Need to transform a rectangle's color in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I have a rectangle, and I have a storyboard:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="PressAndHoldColorBar">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:10" FillBehavior="Stop" Storyboard.TargetName="rectWarning" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Green" />
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:7" Value="Yellow" />
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10" Value="Red" />
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

<Rectangle Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,328,0,0" Name="rectWarning" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200">
```

I want this color change to occur when another button is pressed, so I'm trying to call the code programmatically:

```
s = (Storyboard)this.Resources["PressAndHoldColorBar"];
        s.Begin();
```

I've narrowed it down to Storyboard.TargetName and TargetProperty in the first snippet (I think).  I just need help figuring out what to do to get it to work completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="PressAndHoldColorBar">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:10" FillBehavior="Stop" Storyboard.TargetName="rectWarning" 
                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Green" />
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:7" Value="Yellow" />
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10" Value="Red" />
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

You have to use (Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color).  It doesn't like (Shape.Fill).