# 'myObject' does not contain a property with the name 'ID' (Not a typo)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building an ASP.NET C# website, and I have a dropdownlist that I am binding to a list of objects that I have created. The code that binds the dropdownlist looks like this:

```
protected void PopulateDropdownWithObjects(DropDownList dropdownlist, List<myObject>() myObjects)
{
    dropdownlist.DataValueField = "ID";
    dropdownlist.DataTextField = "Name";
    dropdownlist.DataSource = myObjects;  // my code fails here
    dropdownlist.DataBind();
}
```

However, when it hits the 3rd line within the method, an exception is thrown:

```
DataBinding: 'myObject' does not contain a property with the name 'ID'.
```

However, I can clearly see the myObject.ID value while I debug: I can access it in the Immediate window, it's public, it isn't null, and I spelled it correctly and with the proper case:

```
public class myObject
{
    public int ID;   // see? "ID" is right here!
    public string Name;

    public myObject(
        int id,
        string name
        )
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Is there anything else that can cause this error?

Comment: NO, I don't see a *PROPERTY* name ID.  I see a Field name ID.  Perhaps you need to re-evaluate your definition of "fact" ;)

Comment: For me this question was so much clearer that the one that it 'duplicates'!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your code will not work, because `ID` is a *field*, not a *property*.

If you change your class, as shown below, the code will work as intended:

```
public class myObject
{
    public int ID    // this is now a property
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public myObject(
        int id,
        string name
        )
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking to yourself in second person?

Comment: @GarrisonNeely Yea, why would anyone [ever](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390896/need-to-transform-a-rectangles-color-in-windows-phone-7) use "you" when answering their [own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920579/efficiently-propagating-interface-changes-in-visual-studio) post? [;)](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/133843)

Comment: Stalker.  My answers use "you" instead of "one".  This answer doesn't use "you" in that way.  Typically a user answering his/her own question will acknowledge it in some way.

Comment: Often after banging on my head on something for days [I will post a question with a immediate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346554/can-i-use-extension-methods-and-linq-in-net-2-0-or-3-0/11346555#11346555) just to stop the suffering of other people who may go though the same issue as me (however I agree he should of checked for a duplicate first).